# Interfacing BlueZ without HCI?

Tags: linux-kernel, bluetooth, bluez

Background

I'm trying to get a BlueZ based userspace app running on a embedded Linux board to use `nRF52832` as a Bluetooth connectivity chip. Seems like `nRF52832` [doesn't support the HCI interface](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/103261/nrf52832-hci-firmware/).

- If a Bluetooth device isn't registered as a HCI device (`hciconfig` returning nothing) does that mean it's impossible to use BlueZ for it?
- In [this talk (9:32)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tclS9arLFzk) the BlueZ software architecture mentions HW drivers. Could those mean specific drivers for controlling the chips that don't expose the HCI interface?

Comment: There seems to be an official [GATT driver](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/pc-ble-driver) mentioned in your link. It looks like it provides UART-like connectivity. Have you tried it?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Yes, I perceive that as a Nordic specific API which would vendor lock me to their chip while interfacing the bluetooth devices through BlueZ would remain the API vendor neutral

Answer (score 2):

Alan, did you consider posing it in the linux-bluetooth mailing list? 
http://marc.info/?l=linux-bluetooth
Though most of the posts there are patches and bugs, some questions are about such stuff, and most of these questions are addressed.

Regards,
Rami Rosen